# Getting value of textarea returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have an html form and a js script that gets the value of a textarea. However, when I'm getting the value of the textarea with javascript it return "undefined". 
I have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="contentForm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post" >
<textarea name ="editor" id="editBox" rows="5" cols="2">type</textarea>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function add() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
document.write("hello motto");
var message = "start js";
console.log(message);
var contents = $("#editBox");
var a = contents.val();

if(a === undefined) {
  console.log("contents undefined");
}
console.log(contents);
var item = {"id":"12", "content": contents};
var obj = JSON.stringify(item);
var obj2 = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log("you have arrived"); 
document.write(obj2.id);    
});
}

$(document).ready(function () {

add();  

});
```

I tried the following to get the value of the textarea:

```
var content = $("#editBox").val();
```

and

```
var contents = $("textarea#editBox").val();
```

The val of the textarea is always undefined, with each of the methods I tried.

Is there another method for retrieving the value of a textarea?

Comment: Nothing wrong - both `alert($("#editBox").val());` and `alert($("#editBox").text());` will alert "type"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `document.write` on a closed document will open a new document and destroy the DOM of the existing one.

This destroys the textarea, so when you try to retrieve it to get the value, it does not exist.

Remove the line `document.write("hello motto");`.

Use DOM manipulation to *edit* the existing document, instead of writing a new one.

Comment: Perfect answer! I have a follow-up question: if I preload the textarea with text (like in my code where the string "type" is already in the textarea) the value is retrieved fine. But if I leave the textarea empty and let the user input any text it always comes back undefined.